Problem with ActiveRecord-Session_store gem when starting up Rails 6 app
I'm upgrading a Rails app from v5 to v6.1.7 (ruby:2.7.7), but I have a problem with active_record_store for sessions at start up when running locally in Docker.
I've installed the 'activerecord-session_store' gem, migrated the database, have a  table 'sessions' and all the config described here: https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store
I have an initializer (session_store.rb) with this code:
FAR::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, :key => '_far_session'
but it generates this error:
far-web                | NameError: uninitialized constant ActionDispatch::Session::ActiveRecordStore
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:315:in `session_store'
far-web                | /var/app/far/config/initializers/session_store.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'

Full error output:
rake aborted!
far-web                | `ActiveRecord::SessionStore` is extracted out of Rails into a gem. Please add `activerecord-session_store` to your Gemfile to use it.
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:317:in `rescue in session_store'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:314:in `session_store'
far-web                | /var/app/far/config/initializers/session_store.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `load'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `block in load'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `load'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:681:in `block in load_config_initializer'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:205:in `instrument'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:680:in `load_config_initializer'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:634:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:633:in `each'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:633:in `block in <class:Engine>'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in `initialize!'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/railtie.rb:207:in `public_send'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/railtie.rb:207:in `method_missing'
far-web                | /var/app/far/config/environment.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.17/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:367:in `require_environment!'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:533:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.2.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
far-web                | 
far-web                | Caused by:
far-web                | 
far-web                | NameError: uninitialized constant ActionDispatch::Session::ActiveRecordStore
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:315:in `session_store'
far-web                | /var/app/far/config/initializers/session_store.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:681:in `block in load_config_initializer'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:205:in `instrument'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:680:in `load_config_initializer'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:634:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:633:in `each'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:633:in `block in <class:Engine>'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in `initialize!'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/railtie.rb:207:in `public_send'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/railtie.rb:207:in `method_missing'
far-web                | /var/app/far/config/environment.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.17/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:367:in `require_environment!'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:533:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
far-web                | /usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.2.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'


The app runs fine despite this error; sessions are stored in the database. I could switch to using cookies for session storage:
FAR::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_far_session'
But I need to upload files and cookie storage can't handle file uploads, causing errors when trying to upload files.
I can't ignore this error because of the first line:
rake aborted!
which means the app will fail when I try to deploy it as there are migrations that I need to run when I deploy it.
What am I missing?
It must be something simple, but I can't see the woods for the trees right now.
Any help or ideas would be very much appreciated.

What do you mean "cookie storage can't handle file uploads"? Only if you are putting files in cookies -- which is not wise.

Add your initializer to the question.

Have you tried Rails.application rather than calling the application by name (FAR::Application)? Rails.application calls app_class.instance and instance calls run_load_hooks! which sets a bunch of instance variables, I am not certain your current invocation is doing the same.

Hi engineersmnky, thanks for replying. Yeah, I tried that and it made no difference, it generated the same error. I think the answer is related to /var/app/far/config/initializers/session_store.rb:5:in '<top (required)>'  
but I don't know what the syntax is for this gem (activerecord-session_store) or exactly where to require it

Hi dbugger, thanks for replying. The initializer is above, it only has one line of code: FAR::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, :key => '_far_session'.
I agree files shouldn't be in cookies (security, but also the 4k limit, which causes errors with the files I'm uploading), hence using database storage. I'm uploading data from a CSV for processing and putting into the database. Which works fine, but I know the error above is going to stop me deploying the code to the server.

try adding require activerecord-session_store to the top of your initializer. If that fails try adding require action_dispatch/session/active_record_store

dbugger you're a star!
require action_dispatch/session/active_record_store is the answer, error gone.
Thank you for your help!
